# Cannot read property '0' of undefined - stuck with reactjs tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I stuck at the "Storing a history" part of [the tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html), trying to pull state up from `Board` to `Game`. I've removed constructor from `Board` and was trying to change `Board` so that it takes `squares` via props:

```
 renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square value={this.props.squares[i]} onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)} />;
  }
```

but it fails..

code: https://codepen.io/gka/pen/eBgapz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, you pass in squares as props. So you need to change

```
renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square 
        value={this.props.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
      />;
    );
}
```

into

```
renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square 
        value={this.props[i]}
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
      />;
    );
}
```

Because `this.props` already refers to the squares you passed in.

Answer (score 0):

I had my App render Board instead of Game, so that was the reason it wasn't working.